# mlabwrap setup query

Tags: python, matlab, mlabwrap

I happened to stumble upon an [answer posted by user brentlance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311415/run-a-matlab-script-from-python-pass-args) regarding the linking of Matlab to Python, and was wondering if I could ask the community for some advice regarding the initial setup of the mlabwrap module.

I'm on Windows 7 32 bit, using Matlab R2012a and Python 2.7 (from the Python(x,y) scientific computing package).  When I try to run:

```
python setup.py install
```

in the malbwrap directory, the console returns a very large error, as presented:

```
WINDOWS SPECIFIC ISSUE? Unable to remove c:\users\nathan\appdata\local\temp\tmpv
tzipc; please delete it manually
[Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by anothe
r process: 'c:\\users\\nathan\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmpvtzipc'

running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'mlabraw' extension
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 189, in <module>
    extra_compile_args=EXTRA_COMPILE_ARGS,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 563, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 449, in build_exte
nsions
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 499, in build_exte
nsion
    depends=ext.depends)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 474, in compile
    self.initialize()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 384, in initialize
    vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 300, in query_vcvarsal
l
    raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
ValueError: [u'path']
```

In response to various other issues, I've thus far tried the following:

1. I followed the installation guide posted [here](http://obasic.net/how-to-install-mlabwrap-on-windows)
2. Installed Microsoft VS Express 2010 and SDK version 7.1
3. Set the SDK C++ compiler to the default in Matlab
4. Pointed the msvc9compiler.py script (C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py) at the Common Tools folder for my VS Express install in order to avoid an 'unable to locate vcvarsall.bat' error, as described [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20101221084639/http://nukeit.org/compile-python-2-7-packages-with-visual-studio-2010-express/).

Any help you guys could provide would be greatly appreciated.  Many thanks.

Comment: did you try manually deleting: `c:\users\nathan\appdata\local\temp\tmpv
tzipc`

Comment: Yes.  Unfortunately, the setup script seems to create these temporary files whenever it is run, but cannot delete them (even when I run it from an elevated command prompt).