# Type-Error while using mlabwrap-purepy to call custom functions

Tags: matlab, python-2.7, typeerror, mlabwrap

I downloaded mlabwrap-purepy from: `https://github.com/cpbotha/mlabwrap-purepy`
Next, I call matlab functions using the following:

```
%% Python init <br>
import matlabwrap <br>
mlab = matlabwrap.init() <br>
%% <br>
```

I can easily call all inbuilt matlab functions, but while calling custom functions I run into Type-Error. Consider the following matlab function:

```
%% Matlab Function %% <br>
function [x] = get_x() <br>
  x = 1; <br>
end <br>
%%% <br>
```

when I run, `mlab.get_x()` I get the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'numpy.ndarray' objects <br>
```

Any clues to what might be happening? 
I looked at: [Run a MATLAB script from python + pass args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311415/run-a-matlab-script-from-python-pass-args/13316939#13316939) - but it didn't resolve my issue.

However, when I run simple matlab scripts using mlab.eval with no input args it works, such as:

```
x = mlab.eval('get_x') <br>
```

I would like to be able to run like - `mlab.function_name(arg1,arg2)` - but I hit the error as described above. Any clues to what might fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some help strings to the function get_x().

i.e., in get_x.m file:

```
function [x] = get_x()
% GET_X return x
x = 1;
end
```